# Solr QF and PF Field, is an intersection between them necessary for boosting Purposes

Tags: apache, search, solr, search-engine, solrcloud

I am working with  a solr document set, one of the example document has structure is as follows:

```
{
"field1":"someValue",
"field2":"someValue2",
"field3":"someValue3"
}
```

My QF and PF parameters look as follows:

> qf=field1^200.0 field2^100.0 and pf=field1^200

At the moment I have requirement to boost by field3, in this scenario, am I required to have an intersection between the field in the qf and pf fields. By which I mean do I need to have field3 specified as one of the query fields, before I can use it for boosting or can I use it for boosting regardless of it's presence in the qf field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boost (boost, bf, bq parameters even though you do not include it in qf/pf